# Java: Error: ';' expected

Tags: java

i've been doing some basic java things and while compiling i'm getting some errors and i have no idea why...

```
for (VisibleObject object : spawnedObjects) {
    if (object == null) {spawnedObjects.remove(object); break;}
    if (object.getSpawn().getTemporarySpawn().canDespawn() && object.getSpawn().hasPool()||bypass && object.getSpawn().hasPool()) {
        if ((object instanceof Npc)) {
            Npc npc = (Npc) object;
            if (!npc.getLifeStats().isAlreadyDead()) {
               int object.getSpawn().setUse(false);
                npc.getController().cancelTask(TaskId.RESPAWN);
                object.getController().delete();
                spawnedObjects.remove(object);
            }
```

and it says: 
error: ';' expected
    [javac]                         **int object.getSpawn().setUse(false);**

can anyone help me trying to solve this? D:

Comment: What do you think that line should do and why?

Comment: What do you intend for that line to do?

Comment: What exactly does `int object.getSpawn().setUse(false);` mean?

Comment: When you make an error like that the compiler tries to make sense of it.  The first attempt is probably to consider `int object` as a declaration.  It would then observe that there is no semicolon after that "declaration".  Hence the error message.

Answer (score 2):

The error message isn't clear, but there is definitely something wrong with that line of code:

```
int object.getSpawn().setUse(false);
```

Why are you declaring an `int`?  *How* are you declaring an `int`?  Did you just mean to invoke the method?:

```
object.getSpawn().setUse(false);
```

Or set the result of the method to a variable?:

```
int someVariable = object.getSpawn().setUse(false);
```

Either way, the error is identifying a broken line of code which needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid java code:

```
int object.getSpawn().setUse(false);
```

After you give `int` or any data type, you need to provide variable name like this:

```
int varName = object.getSpawn().setUse(false);
```

But I doubt this work because as a convention `setUse` shouldn't return a value, incase if it is returning in your code, this will work. If it is a void method, above my code won't work, then remove that `int` to make code like this:

```
object.getSpawn().setUse(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a `int` type for variable assignment but you are not assigning anything.
Remove it.

```
int object.getSpawn().setUse(false);
// =>
object.getSpawn().setUse(false);
```